# When will ratings and review for Ubuntu Software Center start?

Tags: software-center

I remember there were announcements, that Ubuntu Software Center should get a rating and review system. Don't know if these announcement were official, but I remember it was stated it could start before Christmas. What's the recent status of these new features?

Comment: According to http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/search-suggestions-in-software-center/ , it's currently being developed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ratings and reviews have now landed in the current development release of 11.04.

Keep in mind that, normally, no major updates are performed within one release. In almost every case, updates are "Stable Release Updates" (SRUs). But see the second part for what will hopefully be an exception in February. :)

[image]

(Image by [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/ubuntu-10-10-software-center-to-get-ratings-and-reviews-on-feb-11th/))

**Software-Center's [Launchpad Project [image]](https://launchpad.net/software-center) page** also has instructions on how to try the latest development version, if you want to check out what's currently going on:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:software-store-developers/daily-build
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This is experimental, unreleased software. If you do decide to try it out, and you encounter a problem, [Report a Bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)  - after making sure it hasn't been reported already.

---

The ubuntu software centre **in Maverick** will get ratings and reviews in February 2011, according to it's [page in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#February%202011)

> We plan to release Ubuntu Software Center 3.2 for Ubuntu 10.10, with one new feature:
>
> - Rating and reviewing software, and seeing ratings and reviews submitted by other Ubuntu users.

Many thanks to @NES for keeping us up to date on it!

Comment: update: Ubuntu 10.10 Software Center to get ratings and reviews on Feb 11th http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/ubuntu-10-10-software-center-to-get-ratings-and-reviews-on-feb-11th/

Answer (score 2):

Ratings and reviews will appear in 11.04 which will contain version 3.2 of the Software Centre.

However [the blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-foundations-n-ratings-and-reviews-in-software-center) says that version 3.2 with Ratings and Reviews support may be officially released as a (compulsory) upgrade in version 10.10. If this does happen it won't happen until at least the end of March.

In the meantime Stefano rightly says you could try adding the ppa, however [there is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/690728) that prevents the ppa package from installing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a collection of information on the topic - on "[OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/ubuntu-software-centre-adds-ratings-and-reviews-in-natty/)"